# Web App-Bot Creation (Azure) - No LUIS App visible

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I'm having a strange issue while creating a new Web App-Bot with Language understanding (LUIS):

After creating the bot within Azure-portal (Web App Bot with LUIS Template) the bot is just working fine with the basic intents (Greeting, Cancel, None,...) but the LUIS app is not visible under "My Apps" at "luis.ai".

Obviously a Luis-app has been created but its not visible in my account.
Any ideas?

For my last bot the creation worked just fine and the LUIS app was visible right away...

Comment: Any chance this is a regions issue - have you checked eu.luis.ai and au.luis.ai as well?

Comment: I guess you were right, i created a new App using "Central US" as LUIS server location and that did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Correct page has to be used according to LUIS server location:
E.g. Western Europe -> eu.luis.ai 
E.g. Central US-> luis.ai.

Answer (score 0):

The region in which you publish your LUIS app corresponds to the [region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions) or location you specify in the Azure portal when you create an Azure LUIS endpoint key.
There are three LUIS websites, based on region. You must author and publish in the same region.

The apps published to any regions except Europe and Australia are available at luis.ai, the apps published in Australia are available in au.luis.ai and the apps published in Europe are available in eu.luis.ai.